# SVG not displayed

Tags: ruby, svg, jekyll

I'm working on a Jekyll project, where I want to use Font Awesome Icon as SVG, without declaring them all at once. So I've wrote a jekyll plugin, which I will convert to a Gem when it will be functionnal, to declare only used icons.

My problem is my HTML code is fine, I can see both the SVG definition and the SVG icon `use` but the icon aren't displayed, I've only got a `shadow root (closed)`.

Can you provide me some help please ?

Here is a live demo where you can find 2 icons : https://deploy-preview-65--pedantic-ramanujan-f13a37.netlify.com/projet/bataille-navale/

Their is a `#fab.fa-dev` and a `#fab.fa-facebook` icon that should be displayed below the image.

The declaration of my svg is

```
<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <defs>
            <symbol id="fab.fa-dev" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
            <title>dev</title>
            <path class="path1" d="&quot;M120.12 208.29c-3.88-2.9-7.77-4.35-11.65-4.35H91.03v104.47h17.45c3.88 0 7.77-1.45 11.65-4.35 3.88-2.9 5.82-7.25 5.82-13.06v-69.65c-.01-5.8-1.96-10.16-5.83-13.06zM404.1 32H43.9C19.7 32 .06 51.59 0 75.8v360.4C.06 460.41 19.7 480 43.9 480h360.2c24.21 0 43.84-19.59 43.9-43.8V75.8c-.06-24.21-19.7-43.8-43.9-43.8zM154.2 291.19c0 18.81-11.61 47.31-48.36 47.25h-46.4V172.98h47.38c35.44 0 47.36 28.46 47.37 47.28l.01 70.93zm100.68-88.66H201.6v38.42h32.57v29.57H201.6v38.41h53.29v29.57h-62.18c-11.16.29-20.44-8.53-20.72-19.69V193.7c-.27-11.15 8.56-20.41 19.71-20.69h63.19l-.01 29.52zm103.64 115.29c-13.2 30.75-36.85 24.63-47.44 0l-38.53-144.8h32.57l29.71 113.72 29.57-113.72h32.58l-38.46 144.8z"></path>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="fab.fa-facebook" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
            <title>facebook</title>
            <path class="path1" d="&quot;M448 56.7v398.5c0 13.7-11.1 24.7-24.7 24.7H309.1V306.5h58.2l8.7-67.6h-67v-43.2c0-19.6 5.4-32.9 33.5-32.9h35.8v-60.5c-6.2-.8-27.4-2.7-52.2-2.7-51.6 0-87 31.5-87 89.4v49.9h-58.4v67.6h58.4V480H24.7C11.1 480 0 468.9 0 455.3V56.7C0 43.1 11.1 32 24.7 32h398.5c13.7 0 24.8 11.1 24.8 24.7z"></path>
        </symbol>

                </defs>
            </svg>
```

I use SVG like this then :

```
<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#fab.fa-dev"></use></svg>
```

If you want more details about the code, see the pull request here : https://github.com/sylvainmetayer/sylvainmetayer/pull/65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In writing the Path formula, you have an invalid quotation mark - `& quot;`

```html
<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <defs>
            <symbol id="fab.fa-dev" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
            <title>dev</title>
            <path class="path1" d="M120.12 208.29c-3.88-2.9-7.77-4.35-11.65-4.35H91.03v104.47h17.45c3.88 0 7.77-1.45 11.65-4.35 3.88-2.9 5.82-7.25 5.82-13.06v-69.65c-.01-5.8-1.96-10.16-5.83-13.06zM404.1 32H43.9C19.7 32 .06 51.59 0 75.8v360.4C.06 460.41 19.7 480 43.9 480h360.2c24.21 0 43.84-19.59 43.9-43.8V75.8c-.06-24.21-19.7-43.8-43.9-43.8zM154.2 291.19c0 18.81-11.61 47.31-48.36 47.25h-46.4V172.98h47.38c35.44 0 47.36 28.46 47.37 47.28l.01 70.93zm100.68-88.66H201.6v38.42h32.57v29.57H201.6v38.41h53.29v29.57h-62.18c-11.16.29-20.44-8.53-20.72-19.69V193.7c-.27-11.15 8.56-20.41 19.71-20.69h63.19l-.01 29.52zm103.64 115.29c-13.2 30.75-36.85 24.63-47.44 0l-38.53-144.8h32.57l29.71 113.72 29.57-113.72h32.58l-38.46 144.8z"></path>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="fab.fa-facebook" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
            <title>facebook</title>
            <path class="path1" d="M448 56.7v398.5c0 13.7-11.1 24.7-24.7 24.7H309.1V306.5h58.2l8.7-67.6h-67v-43.2c0-19.6 5.4-32.9 33.5-32.9h35.8v-60.5c-6.2-.8-27.4-2.7-52.2-2.7-51.6 0-87 31.5-87 89.4v49.9h-58.4v67.6h58.4V480H24.7C11.1 480 0 468.9 0 455.3V56.7C0 43.1 11.1 32 24.7 32h398.5c13.7 0 24.8 11.1 24.8 24.7z"></path>
        </symbol>

                </defs>
</svg> 
   
    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#fab.fa-dev"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#fab.fa-facebook" transform="translate(100,0)"></use>
   
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't saw this typo !